# Counting number of $a\times b $ sub-matrices in a $m\times n$ matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

By observation I figured out that the number of $2\times 3$ sub-matrices in a $n\times n$ matrix is
$2*(n-2)*(n-1)$. Is there a formal way to derive this formula? For the general case, how do to count number of sub-matrices of a given dimension?

Comment: Consider possible positions of the upper left corner of the submatrix.

Answer (score 1):

Your figure actually overcounts by a factor of $2$: it’s the number of submatrices that are either $2\times 3$ **or** $3\times 2$.

For the general result, note that the upper lefthand corner of an $a\times b$ submatrix must be in one of the first $$n-(a-1)=n-a+1$$ rows and in one of the first $$n-(b-1)=n-b+1$$ columns of the matrix, and that it can be in any of these positions. Since an $a\times b$ submatrix is completely determined by the location of its upper lefthand corner, there must be $$(n-a+1)(n-b+1)\tag{1}$$ $a\times b$ submatrices. There are the same number of $b\times a$ submatrices, so if you wish to count both, just double the result in $(1)$ if $a\ne b$.